# validate two column from different dataframes basis unique column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to validate the `Name` column from both data frames if they have different names for the same `ID`.
For the same `ID`, how do you check to see if the names in df and df1 are different names. If so, then mutate a new column to show duplicate names.

doubt : I want to learn while handling this. How can we ignore case of `Names`?

```
df <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2252","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2921","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                 city=c("DEL","mum","DEL","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","mum","mum","mum","mum","DEL","DEL"),
                 Name= c("dev,akash","singh,Ajay","abbas,salman","lal,ram","singh,nkunj","garg,prabal","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"))


df1 <- data.frame(ID =c("DEV2962","KTN2251","ANA2719","ITI2624","DEV2698","HRT2923","","KTN2624","ANA2548","ITI2535","DEV2732","HRT2837","ERV2951","KTN2542","ANA2813","ITI2210"),
                  city=c("DEL","mum","DEL","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","DEL","del","MUM","mum","mum","mum","mum","DEL","DEL"),
                  Name= c("dev,akash","singh,rahul","abbas,salman","lal","singh,nkunj","garg","ali,sanu","singh,kunal","tomar,lakhan","thakur,praveen","ali,sarman","khan,zuber","singh,giriraj","sharma,lokesh","pawar,pooja","sharma,nikita"))



df[[colname1]] <- factor(as.integer(!df[[colname1l]] %in% df[[colname1]]))
```

expected output

[image]

Comment: @RonakShah Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two dataframe and use `ifelse` to check the two `Name` columns.

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df, df1, by = 'ID') %>%
  mutate(diff_name = if_else(Name.x != Name.y,'Different Name', '', missing = ''))
```

In base R -

```
transform(merge(df, df1, by = 'ID', all = TRUE), 
          diff_name = ifelse(Name.x != Name.y, 'Different Name', ''))
```

---

Another approach is to use `match` -

```
df$diff_name <- ''
df$diff_name[df$Name != df1$Name[match(df$ID, df1$ID)]] <- 'Different Name'
```

Comment: if names are Upper case in one dataframe then it will work...??

Comment: If you want the match to be case insensitive use `tolower(Name.x) ! = tolower(Name.y)` in `ifelse`. `

Comment: Thanks , one more thing its changing column names as Name.x, Name.y

if i dont want to change the original df , just mutate with diff_name.

Comment: I didn't understand your comment but you can rename the column `Name.x` to `Name` and drop `Name.y` column if you don't want column names with suffix.

Comment: my question is i want to keep df as it is , only want to mutate new column in df which showing differente name. see the expected output

Comment: Isn't my code already doing that? You have `diff_name` as new column. If you don't want certain columns remove them using  `select(-col1, -col2)` and rename `Name.x` to `Name`.

Comment: Actually in my original data i have many columns and columns are dynamic so i want to make it dynamic also . because i have to change select(-col1, -col2) this every time.

Comment: @user14176250 See my updated answer with `match` which will only add one new column.

Answer (score 0):

We could do this in `base R`

```
out <- merge(df, df1, by = 'ID', all = TRUE)
out$diff_name <- with(out, c('', 'Different Name')[1 + (Name.x != Name.y)])
```